# How to position two elements on the one line in HTML

Tags: html, css

Here is my problem: 
[image]

I need to put this number over"...".

**Here is the HTML code:**

```
<div class=" unread-object">

            <div style="overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">

                <a class="k-link nowrappable outdate-object" href="#/view/19260">
                    л ьотрипмасвчувсапмдгбыцячшльогтрнамам ам маугшпгнплрплроsdsds 
                </a>


                 <span class="unread-count" style="font-weight:normal; font-size:9px; color:rgb(161,187,206);float:right;">[3]</span>


            </div>
        </div>
```

float:right and left doesnt work. But, when I stretch fully slider:

[image]

Comment: i think you can use position:absolute for to place element, => add position:relative for you're second div, and for the span add : position:absolute;top:Xpx; right:0px;

Comment: I think you can use responsive css

Answer (score 2):

use `display:inline-block`

```
<a class="k-link nowrappable outdate-object" href="#/view/19260" style="display:inline-block;">л ьотрипмасвчувсапмдгбыцячшльогтрнамам ам маугшпгнплрплроsdsds</a>

<span class="unread-count" style="font-weight:normal; font-size:9px; color:rgb(161,187,206); display:inline-block;">[3]</span>
```

I think this will solve your issue.

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/wLpaT/)

Answer (score 1):

When the width of the block does not align the two elements, the right will float line.

Simple solution is to use `position:absolute;`

[In my example](http://jsfiddle.net/H99eq/)

I placed `position:relative` for the second div

`<div style="overflow: hidden;position:relative; text-overflow: ellipsis;">`

where you have content and the span with unread-count it's placed with `position absolute;`

```
.unread-object .unread-count{
   position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px
}
```